# Angular `ng add` is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`

Tags: angular

[image: Image2][image: Error Image]

The specified command **add** is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are in the project folder?

Comment: Yes, I am in the project folder sir.

Comment: Can you try to update your angular CLI? The last version of the CLI is 7.2.3 and yours seems outdated.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10469

Comment: @JohanRin I am trying your suggestion sir, but not getting anything

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam I already visited this link sir.

Comment: Try ng add @angular/pwa --project YourProjectName just replace YourProjectName.

Comment: @HenslerSoftware Nope not getting Sir

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with your Angular cli install. Are you able to confirm your Angular CLI version is now > 7?

Comment: @HenslerSoftware Sir question updated.

Comment: Your Angular cli version is still 1.7.4, you need to run ng update --all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to update your Angular cli and Angular.
Please read all of this before copy and pasting the commands into terminal.

The latest version for these are (as of writing this post):-

- Angular (7.2.2)
- Angular CLI (7.2.3)

Once you have update Angular to greater than version 6 you should be able to use the `ng add` command.

In order to update the angular-cli package installed globally in your system, you need to run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

You will also need to update it within your project

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

As your CLI version is still on 1.x you need to convert your angular-cli.json to angular.json, which you can do with the following command:

```
ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --migrate-only
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help :-)

Comment: The ng update doesn't seem to be available anymore either, is there an alternative to the command you have mentioned?